Unable to get comma separated values in Qlik text box for a certain logic
I want a comma separated value in a qliksense text box.
Consider the following data
REGION|MARKET|METRIC|VALUE

ASP|INDIA|S1|1

ASP|CHINA|S1|0

ASP|INDIA|S2|0

ASP|CHINA|S2|1

ASP|HONGK|S1|1

EUR|UK|S1|1

EUR|UK|S2|0

USA|TX|S1|1

USA|TX|S3|1

I want an output in a Qlik Sense text box with the following logic:
Sum of the VALUE column where VALUE=1 for metric S1.
Desired output in text box: ASP(2), EUR(1), USA(1)
I would really appreciate your help.

You can use this statement:
Concat(Aggr(REGION & '(' & Sum({<METRIC={'S1'}>} VALUE) & ')', REGION), ',')

Which will return you the desired result:

In case VALUE is not binary you can add VALUE = {1} to the set expression like:
Concat(Aggr(REGION & '(' & Sum({<METRIC={'S1'}, VALUE = {1}>} VALUE) & ')', REGION), ',')

Statement to load data:
Data:
Load *
Inline [
REGION,MARKET,METRIC,VALUE
ASP,INDIA,S1,1
ASP,CHINA,S1,0
ASP,INDIA,S2,0
ASP,CHINA,S2,1
ASP,HONGK,S1,1
EUR,UK,S1,1
EUR,UK,S2,0
USA,TX,S1,1
USA,TX,S3,1
];


Thank you. I used this statement Concat(Aggr(REGION & '(' & Sum({<METRIC={'S1'}, VALUE = {1}>} VALUE) & ')', REGION), ',') . However, with the data that I have it is resulting into regions repeating. Example: Asia Pacific (3), Canada(1)(2), Asia Pacific (3), Canada (1)

Hm, Aggr() aggregates over REGION. If it returns Asia Pacific and Canada twice or more it doesn't see them as the same. Are there typos in the name or trailing or leading whitespaces?

My bad. I had some text written in the text box. The solution works fine. Thank you! :)
